# Laravel Mass assignment

Tags: laravel

i wanted to use migration with mass assignment. When I do this, I get the error message "MassAssignmentException". I then updated my class with this code:

```
protected $fillable = array('title', 'body', 'published_at');
```

When I do this then:

```
App\Article::create(['title' => 'New article', 'body' => 'New body', 'published_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
```

I still get the same MassAssignmentException. Do I miss something out?

Answer (score 0):

I just exited the Tinker Mode and did an composer update. Then it worked perfectly fine